# Jenkins is unable to download the github repository

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I am trying to download a github repository into my local machine using Jenkins. I got a timeout error stating

ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'

I tried increasing the time to 300 minutes, again I get the same error

ERROR: Timeout after 300 minutes
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'

I am using 2.4.0 version of git plugin in Jenkins.

Can any one please help me to sort it out.

Comment: Can you access the repository from that machine without Jenkins? What are your settings?

Comment: See if this helps http://jakubstas.com/github-and-jenkins-integration

Comment: @SevenEleven: Yes, I am able to access the repository from my machine using tortoise. But am not able to do it with the help of Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to expand the default timeout value of `git checkout` and `git clone`[including `git fetch`].

#### Git Checkout

> Job Settings -> Source Code Management -->Git-->Additional Behaviours-->Advanced Checkout behaviours-->Timeout (in minutes) for checkout operation

#### Git Clone/Fetch

> Job Settings -> Source Code Management -->Git-->Additional Behaviours-->Advanced Checkout behaviours-->Timeout (in minutes) for clone and fetch operations

Comment: I used this step to increase my timeout minutes(300 minutes), but still it comes out with the same error. But when I try to pull the repository manually using Tortoise it takes just 15 to 20 minutes.